# Finding characters in a list python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

```
def find_friend(filename, name):
    lists = open(filename, 'Ur')
    name1 = set(lists)
    for row in lists:
        if name in name1:
            print row
        else:
            print 'friend does not exist'
```

So my desired outcome is opening a list, searching for a character within that list
and returning the character details. for eg. searching for `a` in `[(a,b,c,d),(e,f,g,h)]` would return `a,b,c,d`. So far it isn't returning anything.

Comment: This is kind of unclear but why don't you just check `if name in row`?

Comment: checked that, still throwing out nothing

Comment: Could you please post what the file looks like?

Comment: csv file - 2 rows 4 columns,

John | america | 1/2/03/ | 2315532,
Mary | england | 4/20/03/ | 234232

Comment: To parse a CSV file, use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) module

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue is that the `for row in lists` won't actually iterate through anything (you've already done a complete read of the file when you called `set`). I think if you get rid of that line (and look for `name in row` you should be doing much better.

```
def find_friend(filename, name):
    lists = open(filename, 'Ur')
    for row in lists:
        if name in row:
            print row
        else:
            print 'friend does not exist'
```

Comment: I suggested that as well and apparently it doesn't help him